# Split with regex but with first character of delimiter

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex like this: `"[a-z|A-Z|0-9]: "` that will match one alphanumeric character, colon, and space. I wonder how to split the string but keeping the alphanumeric character in the first result of splitting. I cannot change the regex because there are some cases that the string will have special character before colon and space.

Example:

```
line = re.split("[a-z|A-Z|0-9]: ", "A: ") # Result: ['A', '']
line = re.split("[a-z|A-Z|0-9]: ", ":: )5: ") # Result: [':: )5', '']
line = re.split("[a-z|A-Z|0-9]: ", "Delicious :): I want to eat this again") # Result: ['Delicious :)', 'I want to eat this again']
```

**Update:**
Actually, my problem is splitting from a review file. Suppose I have a file that every line has this pattern: `[title]: [review]`. I want to get the title and review, but some of the titles have a special character before a colon and space, and I don't want to match them. However, it seems that the character before a colon and space that I want to match apparently is an alphanumeric one.

Comment: Please include more splitting examples, along with your current Python script.

Comment: `[a-z|A-Z|0-9]`  also matches a special character, `|`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew So how to use or in regex without matching the special character `|`?

Comment: Just remove `|`, `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I have already added some examples

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

First of all, as you show in your examples, you need to match characters other than `a-zA-Z0-9`, so we should just use the `.` matcher, it will match every character.

So I think the expression you're looking for might be this one:

```
(.*?):(?!.*:) (.*)
```

You can use it like so:

```py
import re

pattern = r"(.*?):(?!.*:) (.*)"
matcher = re.compile(pattern)

txt1 = "A: "
txt2 = ":: )5: "
txt3 = "Delicious :): I want to eat this again"

result1 = matcher.search(txt1).groups() # ('A', '')
result2 = matcher.search(txt2).groups() # (':: )5', '')
result3 = matcher.search(txt3).groups() # ('Delicious :)', 'I want to eat this again')
```

### Explanation

We use capture groups (the parentheses) to get the different parts in the string into different groups, `search` then finds these groups and outputs them in the tuple.

The `(?!.*:)` part is called "Negative Lookahead", and we use it to make sure we start capturing from the **last** `:` we find.

### Edit

BTW, if, as you mentioned, you have many lines each containing a review, you can use this snippet to get all of the reviews separated by title and body at once:

```py
import re

pattern = r"(.*?):(?!.*:) (.*)\n?"
matcher = re.compile(pattern)

reviews = """ 
A: 
:: )5: 
Delicious :): I want to eat this again
"""

parsed_reviews = matcher.findall(reviews) # [('A', ''), (':: )5', ''), ('Delicious :)', 'I want to eat this again')]
```

Comment: I have already updated my question. Maybe I'm confused with the `delimiter` definition.

Answer (score 0):

You could split using a negative lookbehind with a single colon or use a character class `[:)]` where you can specify which characters should not occur directly to the left.

```
(?<!:):[ ]
```

In parts

- `(?<!:)` Negative lookbehind, assert what is on the left is not a colon
- `:[ ]` Match a colon followed by a space (Added square brackets only for clarity)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hRghxJ/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/PCJJel)

For example

```
import re
pattern = r"(?<!:): "
line = re.split(pattern, "A: ") # Result: ['A', '']
print(line)
line = re.split(pattern, ":: )5: ") # Result: [':: )5', '']
print(line)
line = re.split(pattern, "Delicious :): I want to eat this again") # Result: ['Delicious :)', 'I want to eat this again']
print(line)
```

Output

```
['A', '']
[':: )5', '']
['Delicious :)', 'I want to eat this again']
```